# Completely disable item validation or cancel output for a specific item

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Problem in $.validate() method

Tried to specify various options from here https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/ but never got the desired result.

```
    $("#form1").validate(
    {
      ignore: "input.ignore",
      rules:
      {
        i1: {'not_empty': true},
        i2: {'not_empty': true}
      }
    }
    );

    jQuery.validator.addMethod
    (
        'not_empty',
        function(value, element) 
        {
            return checkNotEmpty(value);
        }, 
        function(value, element) 
        {
            return "Not empty!";
        }
    );

    function checkNotEmpty(value)
    {
      return jQuery.trim(value).length > 0;
    }    

    $('#bv').click(function (event) 
    {
        $("#form1").valid();
    });
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gt4nj60L/
The i1-i3 fields are pre-defined with some error texts. In this case, the i2 field is excluded from validation, and i3 is not even added to the validation. But during validation, the error is cleared for the i2 and i3 fields. Is it possible to somehow by standard means by specifying options for validate () to ensure that these errors are not erased?

I need the  with errors not to be erased in certain cases. These errors are generated by other validation mechanisms that work in parallel with jquery-validate. For each field, only one error should be indicated at a time. In this regard, in other mechanisms for the validation of their error, I bring to the field (), which coincides with the default jquery-validate error field

P.S. Sorry for bad English...(

Comment: Please place full demo code within your OP.  Do not rely solely on jsFiddle.

Comment: There are quite a few things wrong here.  First, the `.validate()` method should not be inside of a `click` handler.  It's the initialization method of the plugin and only gets called once on page load.  Secondly: *"These errors are generated by other validation mechanisms that work in parallel with jquery-validate."* ~ then maybe you should not be using the jQuery Validate plugin as it was not meant for you to use other validation in parallel.  However, this plugin allows you to customize it entirely and there are no limits to the custom rules you can create.

Comment: 1. Done.
2. Done. Although it does not matter in this case. About parallel mechanism... I use another third-party component to upload files. And it is necessary to do its own validation (since there is not one object for validation but a lot of files). And for all other elements I use jquery-validate. The question is, how do I configure jquery-validate so that, for example, in the case of the presence of a <label> element with an error the validator does not do anything with it? The source of jquery-validate cannot be changed

Comment: Search SO and look at examples.  There’s several thousand tagged for this plugin.

Comment: Sparky I know. In the beginning, I spent a few days searching for solutions and testing various jquery-validate options. And only then I asked the question here. I always ask something here only in hopeless cases, when I have already tried all the options I could think of